# How to say “one’s” or “someone’s” in German?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-case, genitive

For example:

> It’s a necessary stage in one’s development.

Should it be:

> Es ist eine notwendige Stufe jemander Entwicklung?

Or

> Es ist eine notwendige Stufe jemandes Entwicklung?

I thought it should be the former, as *Entwicklung* is a feminine noun, but then I saw [this sentence on Tatoeba](http://tatoeba.org/deu/sentences/show/1884513):

> Tom found someone’s business card in his pocket, but couldn’t remember where he got it
>
> Tom fand jemandes Visitenkarte in seiner Tasche, doch er konnte sich nicht besinnen, wo er diese herhatte.

Here *Karte* is a feminine noun but jemandes is used.

Comment: Hi and welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Feel free to take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. The thing is that the genitive of nouns is not modified by the noun following it unlike adjectives. So the genitive of *jemand* is always *jemandes: Jemandes Hund, jemandes Maus, jemandes Eichhörnchen.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Jemandes Entwicklung* is grammatically correct, however it sounds pretty ghastly.

I think there are two possible ways to translate your first sentence *comfortably*, but I would half avoid a direct translation.

I mean this in the sense that you say in English **“it** is a necessary stage”, then you use *one’s*, but actually we haven’t really intrduced exactly **who** this *one* is. In English it is clearly a passive construction, however in German there isn’t a nice way of expressing *one’s* — referring back to a person we haven’t yet introduced. Furthermore, there is no genitive form of *man* (English *one*), it only exists in the nominative, with possessive form (*sein*) and reflexive (*sich*).

I would rephrase the German to use **man** — in place of the English clause: *it is a necessary …*
After doing this, we can refer back to our **man** (the indefinite pronoun) using *sein* or the reflexive *sich:*

> - Zum Zwecke seiner Entwicklung muss man diese notwendige Phase überwinden.
> - Man muss diese notwendige Phase überwinden, um sich zu entwickeln.

A more direct way might be the following.

> bei der Entwicklung eines Menschen ist es eine notwendige Phase/Stufe.

As a final note, I’d like to point out that these constructions are very uncommon i.e. using the genitive of personal pronouns. The most common way by far to express possession is to postposition *von* plus the person’s name. There may also (in South Germany) be the definite article thrown in for good measure. E.g:

> Hier ist die Handtasche von (der) Maria

Other variants one might hear (*Weitere Varianten, die man vielleicht hört*):

> Hier ist Marias Handtasche   [*Maria* in genitive]
>   Hier ist die Handtasche der Maria     [Maria again in genitive, shown by the article]

Another alternative to my first sentence would be *die Entwicklung desjenigen*

I listed them in descending order of usage (in my own experience!)

Comment: Thank you. The genitive will be the death of me, I know that.

Comment: What do you consider "dEnglish" when using "Marias Handtasche"?

Comment: @Jan - dEnglish = deutsches Englisch - a mish-mash of languages. German (and many others) adopt traits from English, mainly due to popular culture (e.g. American cinema and music). ["When showing possession with the names of people, countries or cities, German adds an `s` (without an apostrophe): Marias Buch, die Geschichte Deutschlands (Germany's history). Unfortunately, many German-speakers have adopted the English practice of using an apostrophe (Karl's Auto) for the possessive forms, but it is still considered to be substandard German."](http://german.about.com/library/blcase_gen.htm)

Comment: Ja, aber warum das große E in dEnglisch? Denglisch kenn ich ja...

Comment: Ich wollte es bloß hervorheben, dass ich keinen Tippfehler gemacht habe. Natürlich weiß ich, dass keine Wörter GroßBuchStaBen haben, die **nicht** am Anfang sind  :-)

Comment: Mal angesehen von der Schreibung; inwiefern soll _Marias Handtasche_ Denglisch sein?

Comment: Entschuldigung, es war nicht meine Absicht, jemanden zu beleidigen mit dem kleinen Witz. Ich lösche es.

Comment: @DexterMorgan Niemand ist beleidigt, aber "Marias Handtasche" ist eben völlig *korrektes* Deutsch. "Denglisch"  und *falsch* ist der sog. "Deppenapostroph" in "Maria's Handtasche".

Comment: The first sentence in this answer is extremely misleading. "Jemandes Entwicklung" is perfectly standard German and does not sound ghastly at all. It's just something that's not used much in conversational German any more, but in written German it's still quite common and does not seem to be disappearing. But "Stufe jemandes Entwicklung" does not just sound ghastly, it is absolutely ungrammatical. Since this double genitive simply doesn't work, it must be rephrased, e.g. as "Stufe in jemandes Entwicklung".

Comment: @HansAdler  +1 - you're completely right. I guess it is just to me that things that aren't actually spoken do _sound_ ghastly upon being spoken.